# Find all entire functions with $|f(z)|\geq e^{|z|}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Find all entire functions with $|f(z)|\geq e^{|z|}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I don't think there is any such entire function, and here is my thought: since $\Re(z) \leq |z|$, we know $|e^z|\leq  e^{|z|}\leq |f(z)|$ for all $z$. Consider $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$. Since $e^z$ is never $0$, $g(z)$ is an entire function. But $|g(z)| \geq 1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, so there is a contradiction.

I was wondering is there any hole in the preceding argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the inequality it follows that $f$ is never zero.

Therefore $1/f$ is entire and $|1/f|\leq e^{-|z|}\leq1$. Therefore $f$ ought to be constant.

But $e^{|z|}\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$.

...

You probably don't want that, but in a sense $f(z)=\infty\in S^2$ is constant, therefore analytic everywhere, and $|f(z)|\geq e^{|z|}$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me. Assuming $|f(z)|\geq e^{|z|}$ we get that $g(z)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}f(z) e^{-z}$ is an entire function whose modulus is always $\geq 1$, but that contradicts [Picard's little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicardsLittleTheorem.html) or just Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem, stating that if $f$ is a non-constant entire function then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for completing the contradiction argument!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more complicated than necessary.  $|f(z)| \ge e^{|z|} \ge 1$, so  why not just use $f$ instead of $g$?

And, by the way, what are you contradicting?

Comment: I see your point. My contradiction is  that since the range of an entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, if $|g(z)|\geq 1$ for all $z$, then $g$ cannot be an entire function.

Comment: Unless it is constant...

Comment: Sure, but apparently a constant cannot be greater than all $e^{|z|}$. Sorry I should have made it clear in the first place.